# How to send message to all actor in ShardRegion

Tags: java, scala, akka

In my project i must send message to all actors in ShardRegion. I would like to know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options.

Two of them are:

1. You can use [Akka Cluster Singleton](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-singleton.html) Actor which could collect actorRefs for each shard region and dispatch messages in some defined way.
2. Use [Akka Distributed PubSub](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/distributed-pub-sub.html) and subscribe by shardId